# Can you identify this game from 1991 or before?

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Can you identify this game? This is a scanned picture from *Top Secret* games magazine from 1991. It was used as an illustration for the game "Purple Saturn Day," but nothing in this game looks like this.

[Here you can see what "Purple Saturn Day" looks like](https://www.lemonamiga.com/games/details.php?id=1801).

I used Google image search and TinEye, but no luck.

[image]

Comment: A little reminiscent of R-Type

Comment: This question has already been answered and upvoted, however, it would probably have been better to ask it on [gaming.se].

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is ["X Multiply,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Multiply) a side-scrolling shoot-em-up released by Irem (perhaps best known from another stylistically similar shooter series, "R-Type") in 1989.  The characteristic "tentacles" extending from the ship are quite distinctive.  I saw the tentacles and knew that I had played this game; however, I have played a lot of old video games, and it took me a little while to track down the name of the game and additional details about it.

[image: Arcade Flyer]

[image: X Multiply]

You can see a [complete playthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSkzaUVX8fo) of the Playstation re-release on YouTube.  The magazine image is from level 6.

Comment: That bottom screenshot definitely reminded me of R-Type, though I couldn't remember the name either.

Comment: Game play is _extremely_ R-Type, possibly slightly faster.

Comment: @Clockwork Yes, the game really is quite similar to R-Type.  The visual esthetics are very close (including the lettering styles); presumably this was by design.  Moreover, watching the gameplay video, some of the enemies' moved in ways that made me think they might just have been reskinned R-Type enemies.  Given that I was a big fan of the arcade R-Type games, I am actually surprised that I didn't play this game more when it became available.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier It does look fast.